# Is it possible to use 2 different frameworks in 1 backend of a web app?

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, flask, backend

I am an 11th grade student and I'm learning how to build a web app, with my teammates. Currently, We're making a website showing the school schedule (also to show students' marks) and helping the users to create their to-do lists, of course this web serves students like me. In the backend of the web, we use Python as the main language, Flask as the framework and MySQL to manipulate our database. Now, everything is ok and we're trying to make something like an admin interface for people who host the web. Specifically, it is where teachers can insert their students' grade, and maybe adjust the school timetable. The problem is, we're learning how to use Flask Admin to code that function, and we've found out this tech is only compatible with SQL Server. However, we have a better understand in MySQL therefore we could create multiple tasks, in contrast, we don't know how to use SQL Server to create those funcs. Now I have 2 main questions:

1. Could we use 2 different SQL in the backend of our web? It is the quickest way we know, however we have to learn how to use SQL Server.
2. Could we use 2 different Python backend frameworks in the backend of our web? We haven't searched which framework to use yet because we don't know if it's possible to do this.

We don't know any other ways to solve this problem except getting rid of MySQL and use SQL Server instead. However this is not the way we prefer and we hope those 2 questions answered. If there is anything wrong in our knowledge please just straightly comment to let us know, and we greatly welcome any other solutions. Thanks for answering!!

Comment: Flask Admin seems to use SQLAlchemy and doesn’t say anywhere it requires SQL Server when I checked. Where did you see this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly from the flask-admin docs https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#using-different-database-backends is the following:

> Using Different Database Backends Other than SQLAlchemy… There are
> five different backends for you to choose from, depending on which
> database you would like to use for your application. If, however, you
> need to implement your own database backend, have a look at Adding A
> Model Backend.
>
> If you don’t know where to start, but you’re familiar with relational
> databases, then you should probably look at using **SQLAlchemy**. **It
> is a full-featured toolkit, with support for** SQLite, PostgreSQL,
> **MySQL**, Oracle and MS-SQL amongst others. It really comes into its own once you have lots of data, and a fair amount of relations between
> your data models. If you want to track spatial data like
> latitude/longitude points, you should look into GeoAlchemy, as well.

Regarding the original question, it is possible to use two different frameworks in the backend of a web app. One way to do so would be to set up a reverse proxy server (see [https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/#:~:text=A%20reverse%20proxy%20server%20is,traffic%20between%20clients%20and%20servers.](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/#:%7E:text=A%20reverse%20proxy%20server%20is,traffic%20between%20clients%20and%20servers.)), but I would recommend giving SQLAlchemy before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that flask-admin is tied to SqlServer? Flask (and flask-admin) can handle different connections to various databases:

- https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin#introduction
- https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.9/db/

My guess is you are currently using SqlAlchemy. As explained [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine), you can use different backends:

> The string form of the URL is `dialect[+driver]://user:password@host/dbname[?key=value..]`, where `dialect` is a database name such as *mysql, oracle, postgresql, etc.*, and driver the name of a DBAPI, such as *psycopg2, pyodbc, cx_oracle,* etc.
> Alternatively, the URL can be an instance of URL.
> (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine)

More on Engine [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html)

Flask-admin is a *admin* view on your database tables - you cannot run it on a "different" db then the tables it should modify. It needs to have access to the database tables you want it to modify, so you cannot run "admin" on MS and "your data backend" on another database(-connection).

---

Some other things to think about:

MS-(T-)Sql  and MySql are infrastructural choices, language wise they are very closely related so adapting MySql knowledge to T-SQL Syntax should be possible. Choosing SqlServer may force you to license it - and afaik that comes with fees (eiter on premise or as a azure subscription wich might or might not be free for schools (no idea - but you should check that)).

This sounds like an ambitious project for school - depending on where you live, privat data protection laws come into play especially considering you connect names with schedules with grades which would need you to implement a lot more to comply.

Answer (score 0):

For first question, I checked `flask-admin` documentation and found that the framework already included serval built-in ORM library, i.e. `SQLAlchemy`, `MongoEngine`, `pymongo` and `Peewee`. This means you can just directly import the ORM library from the `flask-admin` package and use it to access your database. For your case, you should look for `SQLAlchemy` as you are using SQL Database. Both SQL Server and MySQL are supported by `SQLAlchemy`.

The Adding Model Views section in their official doc also mentioned it as well:
https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/#getting-started

For the second question, it is technically not possible to apply two different frameworks in one single backend application.